# How to add a callback to phantomJS onLoadFinished

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm trying to automate the navigation of some web pages with phantomJS.
What i'm trying to create is a pattern for testing and navigation, so far i got this.

For a moment ignore all the potential null pointers due to empty arrays and such :)

### testSuite.js

```
var webPage = require('webpage');

// Test suite definition
function testSuite(name){

    this.name=name;
    this.startDate=new Date();
    this.tests=[];
    this.add=function(test){
        this.tests.push(test);
    };
    this.start=function(){
        console.log("Test Suite ["+this.name+"] - Start");
        this.next();
    },
    this.next=function(){
        console.log("neeext");
        console.log(this.tests.length);
        var test=this.tests[0];
        this.tests.splice(0,1);
        console.log("Test ["+ test.name+"]");
        test.execute();
    };
}

//Test definition
function test(name,testFunction){
    this.name=name;
    this.execute=testFunction;
}


module.exports.testSuite=testSuite;
module.exports.test=test;
```

### FirstPageModule.js

```
    var currentPage;

    function onPageLoadFinished(status) {
        var url = currentPage.url;
        var filename='snapshot.png';
        console.log("---------------------------------------------------------------");
        console.log("Status:  " + status);
        console.log("Loaded:  " + url);
        console.log("Render filename:" + filename);
        console.log("---------------------------------------------------------------");

        if(status == 'success'){
            currentPage.render(filename);
        }   

        if(status=='fail'){
            console.log("Status:  " + status);
        }

    }

function open(){
    currentPage.open("http://localhost:8080");
}

function login(){

    var username="topSecretUsername";
    var password="topSecretPassord";
    currentPage.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"); 
    currentPage.evaluate(function(user,pass) {

            $("#user").val(user);
            $("#pass").val(pass);
    },username,password);

    currentPage.render("page.png");

    currentPage.evaluate(function(){
        $('#loginButton').click();
    });

}

    function FirstPage(){
        var page = webPage.create();
        currentPage=page;
        this.testSuite = new testSuite("FirstPageModule");
        this.testSuite.add(new test("Open First Page",open));
        this.testSuite.add(new test("Login",login));

        var onLoadFinished=onPageLoadFinished;
        var callNextTest=this.testSuite.next;

        currentPage.onLoadFinished=function(status){
            onLoadFinished.apply(this,arguments);
            callNextTest();
        };

        page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
          console.log(msg);
        }


    }

module.exports=new FirstPage();
```

### PageTests.js

```
 var firstPage=require('./FirstPageModule.js');
 firstPage.testSuite.start();
```

What i want to do is to have a sequential execution of isolated functions, after each function gets executed, i take a screenshot and call the next function.

But, for some reason, the next method on the testSuite isn't getting called, or the method on the second test isn't getting executed.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. Be aware of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/266187).

Comment: I changed to question and provided the full code i'm using and clarified things. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just make available the logName variable in the "global" scope :

```
var logName;

function onPageLoadComplete(status){
    console.log(status);
    // Call the logName function
    if(typeof(logName) == "function"){
        logName();
    }
}

function test(){
    var page = webPage.create();
    this.name="TestName";
    // Update logName value as a function.
    logName = function(){
        console.log(this.name);
    }

    page.onLoadFinished = onPageLoadComplete;
}
```

Primary, it doesn't seems to be related to phantomjs but only plain javascript, i hope that's what you need, otherwise please be more specific with your question.

Comment: I want to export the function test as a models module. Will your solution work in such context?

Comment: @CarlosFerreira sorry, i don't understand what you mean with export as a models module. If you are afraid of modifying a variable with the same name in the context, you can wrap all the previous code within a function. (function(){ // here all the code of the answer })();

Comment: And changed to question and provided the full code i'm using and clarified things. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own `page.get` implementation with a callback when a page is fully loaded.

ex: create a file module `pageSupport.js`

```
// attach listeners
Object.prototype.listeners = {};

// store and fire listeners
Object.prototype.addEventListener = function(event, callback) {

    if (!this.listeners[event]) this.listeners[event] = [];

    this.listeners[event].push(callback);

    this[event] = function(e) {
        if (listeners[event]) {
            listeners[event].forEach(function(listener) { 
                listener.call(null, e);
            });
        }
    }
} 

// create a new reference to webpage.open method
Object.prototype._open = Object.open;

// receive an url and 
// return a function success that will be called when page is loaded.
Object.prototype.get = function(url) {
    return {
        success : function(callback) {
            this.open(url);
            this.addEventListener('onLoadFinished', function(status) {
                if (status == 'success') {
                    return callback(status);
                }
            });
        }.bind(this)
    }
}

// export as phantomjs module.
exports.Object = Object;
```

So you can call this module in your script and uses it as follows:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
           require('./pageSupport');

page.get('http://stackoverflow.com').success(function(status) {

  // Now this callback will be called only when the page is fully loaded \o/
  console.log(status); // logs success
});
```